# Consecutio temporum in German prepositions

Tags: preposition, tense, pluperfect

Just wondering if *nachdem* is the only preposition which induces a change in the tenses:

> Nachdem wir gegessen *hatten*, bin ich nach Hause gefahren.

As far as I know, here it wouldn't be correct to keep both sentences with the same grammatical tense:

> Nachdem wir gegessen *haben*, bin ich nach Hause gefahren. ← falsch(?)

- Is this true?
- Is *nachdem* the only preposition which needs this *consecutio temporum*?

For instance, the original sentence would be quite the same as:

> Bevor ich nach Hause gefahren bin, *haben* wir gegessen.

Shouldn't I use here `Plusquamperfekt` in the subordinate clausule for sake of consistency? Or is this last sentence wrong?

Comment: I would say that the example "Nachdem wir gegessen haben, bin ich..." is maybe not 100% correct but not unheard of... I think the notion of perfectiveness makes it bearable. Anyway, it really doesn't work for the present "Nachdem ich esse schlafe ich." so... nice question

Comment: @Emanuel You can also use it for present: "Nachdem ich esse, werde ich schlafen." If you prefer a perfect tense in the `nachdem`-clause, then present if of course not possible, but present perfect is: "Nachdem ich gegessen habe, werde ich schlafen."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consecutio temporum was part of the German gramma and therefore is kept as such by some people. (See [its German wikipedia entry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutio_temporum) for that.) In the usual language (in spoken rather than written), it can be used but is neither required nor expected. So, as long as you don't use a relatively future tense for the relatively past tense, it's more or less up to you, what you choose:

> Nachdem wir gegessen hatten, bin ich nach Hause gefahren. → OK
>
> Nachdem wir gegessen haben, bin ich nach Hause gefahren. → OK
>
> Nachdem wir gegessen haben, fahre ich nach Hause. → OK
>
> Nachdem wir aßen, bin ich nach Hause gefahren. → OK (Sounds a little bit strange, but the usual speaker wouldn't grasp what's different to the usual strangeness of Preterite.)
>
> Nachdem wir aßen, fuhr ich nach Hause.  → OK
>
> Nachdem wir essen, fahre ich nach Hause. → OK
>
> Nachdem wir essen, fuhr ich nach Hause. → not OK
>
> Nachdem wir essen, bin ich nach Hause gefahren. → not OK
>
> Nachdem wir gegessen haben, war ich nach Hause gefahren. → even that is OK, because Plusquamperfekt isn't used in usual language, so nobody would mind.

Comment: *Nachdem wir essen, fahre ich nach Hause* is ok? I don't think it is, at least it sounds rather (very!!) strange to me. *Nachdem* references an action from the past, so the correct (even though unusual) construct should be *Nachdem wir gegessen haben werden, werde ich nach Hause fahren (fahre ich nach Hause)*. You can, however, say *Nach dem Essen fahre ich nach Hause*.

Comment: Thorsten Dittmar: I think it sounds unfamiliar, but I think it is correct.