# Temporalsatz mit "nachdem"

Tags: grammar, relative-clause, tense

Ich lerne den Temporalsatz mit der Konjunktion *nachdem* und lese [hier](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=101) die Zeitstufen der Verben in Haupt- und Nebensatz. In meinem Buch habe ich auch gelesen, dass Haupt- und Nebensatzverben unterschiedliche Zeitformen haben. Wenn ich es richtig verstehe, habe ich drei Verbindungen zwischen den Zeitstufen des Verbs in Haupt- und Nebensatz:

[image: Verbzeitentabelle]

Meine Frage ist, welche Zeitformen entsprechen der Zukunft und Vergangenheit?

Ich denke, der Zukunft entsprechen das *Futur I* und das *Futur II*, und der Vergangenheit im dritten Fall entsprechen das *Präteritum* und das *Perfekt* (nicht das Plusquamperfekt, denn das Haupt- und das Nebensatzverb haben unterschiedlichen Zeitformen).

Aber ich weiß nicht, ob das korrekt ist!

Comment: Ich befürchte, ich verstehe nicht ganz genau was mit Fälle meinst. [Aber diese Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/consecutio-temporum-in-german-prepositions) scheint, nicht unzusammenhängend zu sein.

Comment: @c.p., ich habe mein Posting korregiert, ich hoffe, dass es jetzt klar/besser ist.

Comment: @Jan, du hast Recht, pardon, ich habe mein Posting korregiert. Ist alles in Ordnung?

Comment: @Jan, Ich danke dir :) .. aber ich weiß nicht, wie ich besser das Posting schreiben kann! Ich bin Italiener und lerne Deutsch c.a seit 5 Monaten

Comment: @Jan, es ist perfekt, alles klar! Danke :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soweit ich das überblicke, hast du mit deiner Vermutung recht, dass Zukunft hier alle Zukunftszeiten einschließt. Nicht sicher bin ich bei der Vergangenheit. Hier eine Auswahl von Testsätzen, die alle Fälle abdecken:

- Futur I/II + Präteritum/Perfekt

  > Ich werde kommen, nachdem ich gegangen bin.
  >   Ich werde kommen, nachdem ich ging.
  >   Ich werde gekommen sein, nachdem ich gegangen bin.
  >   Ich werde gekommen sein, nachdem ich ging.
- Präsens + Präteritum/Perfekt

  > Ich komme, nachdem ich gegangen bin.
  >   Ich komme, nachdem ich ging.
- Präteritum/Perfekt + Plusquamperfekt

  > Ich kam, nachdem ich gegangen war.
  >   Ich bin gekommen, nachdem ich gegangen war.

Es wäre jetzt interessant zu wissen, was der Stern nach *Vergangenheit* in deiner Quelle bedeuten soll. Es ist nämlich so, dass die Sätze mit Präteritum im Nebensatz einen extrem seltsamen Klang haben. Nach einiger Überlegung kann ich mir auch nicht einmal schriftsprachliche Beispiele denken (umgangssprachlich ist das Präteritum sowieso so gut wie tot), wo man einen solchen Satz konstruieren würde. Ich glaube nicht, dass diese Sätze grammatisch falsch sind, aber sie sind definitiv völlig ungebräuchlich.

Comment: danke für deine Antwort ;)

Comment: »umgangssprachlich ist das Präteritum sowieso so gut wie tot« … das stimmt so streng nicht! Ich bin als überzeugter Südler in den Norden gekommen, und stölpere ständig über die Präterita einer Kollegin.