# Ist: "Bevor du kamst, war ich schon fertig" richtig?

Tags: tense

Welche Zeiten brauche ich in einem Satz wie diesem? Ich bin wirklich nicht sicher was ich benutzen soll. So wie oben habe ich den Satz schon gehört und es hört sich auch richtig an, allerdings dachte ich mir zuerst, bei zwei Ereignissen in der Vergangenheit muss man einmal Plusquamperfekt benutzen. Aber auch hier weiß ich nicht, bei welchen der beiden, im Satz oben. Angenommen man muss einmal Plusquamperfekt nehmen; kann man dann beim zweiten Verb normale Vergangenheit oder Perfekt nehmen, je nachdem was sich besser anhört? Zum Beispiel sagt, glaube ich, niemand, bei einem Verb wie "essen" "aß", sondern immer "habe gegessen".

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen "Bevor du kamst, aß ich" (oder ersatzweise "... habe ich gegessen") und "Bevor du kamst, hatte ich gegessen" ist wohl, dass ich im letzteren Fall schon fertig war und im ersten eher durch die Ankunft beim Essen unterbrochen wurde ...

Comment: Der entscheidende Unterschied zwischen "essen" und "fertig sein" ist, dass ersteres eine Handlung, zweiteres aber ein Zustand ist (auch wenn es ein Ereignis gab, an dem man "fertig wurde"). Ergibt der Satz so mehr Sinn für dich?

Comment: Related (non-dupe): [Consecutio temporum in German prepositions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/consecutio-temporum-in-german-prepositions)

Comment: Ich glaube das ich es jetzt verstanden habe danke.

Answer (score 4):

Präteritum/Präteritum: In deinem Beispiel ("bevor du kamst, aß ich") macht das Zeitadverb "bevor" zwar den zeitliche Reihenfolge deutlich, lässt aber *unbestimmt*, ob ich "*fertig* aß".

Präteritum/Perfekt: "bevor du kamst, habe ich gegessen": Das Essen (Handlung 1) begann vor dem Kommen, endet aber vor oder mit dem Kommen (Handlung 2). Auch hier bleibt *unbestimmt*, ob ich nun "fertig gegessen habe". Ausdrücken lässt sich das aber so: "bevor du kamst, habe ich fertig gegessen / aufgegessen / mein Mahl beendet usw.", also mit anderen Verben oder Wendungen, oder auch mit dem Plusquamperfekt.

Wie Hagen kommentiert, macht das Plusquamperfekt mit Präteritum oder Perfekt definitiv klar, dass eine Handlung vor einer anderen stattgefunden hat ("du kamst, ich hatte gegessen" bzw. "du bist gekommen, ich hatte gegessen"). Es liegt auch eine Betonung auf diesem Sachverhalt.

Ob für die andere Handlung (das Kommen) nun Präteritum oder Perfekt verwendet wird, hängt eher von der generell verwendeten Erzählzeit ab (schriftlich und eher im nördlichen Sprachraum: Präteritum, also "ich hatte gegessen, bevor du kamst"; mündlich im südlichen Sprachraum: Perfekt, also "ich hatte (schon) gegessen, bevor du gekommen bist" bzw. "ich hatte (schon) gegessen, bevor du kamst" - beachte evtl. den Einschub der Partikel "schon".)
Zur Reihenfolge: Da ich eine Ich-Erzählung annehme, wird tendenziell der "mich" betreffende Teil des Satzes vorne stehen.

[Deine Lösung mit "Plusquamperfekt + was sich besser anhört" ist zwar nicht eben präzise, ist aber meist die einfachste Lösung. Im schriftlichen Standarddeutsch  ist das Präteritum  die übliche Erzählzeit. Als Sprecher in Österreich verwende ich aber gerade mündlich immer das Perfekt als Erzählzeit, und es ist auch schriftlich bedingt zulässig.]

**Kurz: 
Plusquamperfekt + Erzählzeit zeigt am deutlichsten an, welches Ereignis zuerst stattfindet und abgeschlossen wird, bevor ein zweites Ereignis folgt. 
Die Erzählzeit ist standardmäßig Präteritum, lokal aber auch Perfekt.**

Answer (score 4):

Das Thema der Zeitformen ist in jeder Sprache ziemlich tricky. Im Deutschen ist dies nicht anders. In dieser Antwort versuche ich es so weit es geht zu Vereinfachen, eine umfassende Antwort ist für diese Platform zu groß.

**Perfekt vs Präteritum**

Grob vereinfacht bilden im Deutschen die beiden Sprache die **gleiche** Zeitform. Es gibt keinen Unterschied zwischen "Gestern ging ich zur Schule." und "Gestern bin ich zur Schule gegangen.". Das bedeutet im Wesentliche, wann immer du etwas aus der Vergangenheit erzählst, kannst du zu beiden Zeitformen greifen. In der Umgangssprache wird in aller Regel jedoch das Perfekt bevorzugt, und in geschriebenen Texten findet sich eher das Präteritum.
Gängige Ausnahme bildet hier *haben*, *sein* und Modalverben, die meist auch in der Umgangssprache im Präteritum stehen. Daher ist "Ich war fertig." gängiger als "Ich bin fertig gewesen.".
Die Funktion, die das Perfekt in anderen Sprachen hat, sticht im Deutschen nicht hervor, da wir ja sowieso (fast) immer zum Perfekt greifen.

**Plusquamperfekt** und **Präteritum**

Das Plusquamperfekt wird verwendet, um Vorzeitigkeit in der Vergangenheit wiederzugeben. Wenn zwei Ereignisse in der Vergangenheit geschahen, das eine Ereignis jedoch zuerst vorkam, so findet das Plusquamperfekt seinen Einsatz. Daher wäre es korrekt zu sagen:

> Bevor du kamst, war ich essen gegangen.
>   Ich war schon essen gegangen, als du kamst.

Auch hier sind wir im Deutschen aber nicht immer so korrekt. Im beiden Sätzen kann man durchaus das Partizip auslassen (auch wenn sich semantisch die Bedeutung leicht ändert) und nicht selten greift man zum Präteritum. Das ist möglich, weil das Wort "bevor" angibt, in welcher Reihenfolge die Ereignisse geschahen. Daher sind die beiden folgenden Sätze in der Praxis durchaus anzutreffen.

> Bevor du kamst, war ich essen.
>   Bevor du kamst, ging ich essen.

Und doch drücken die Sätze etwas anderes aus. Im ersten Satz kann man davon ausgehen, dass ich wieder zurück war, als du kamst. Der zweite Satz drückt zwei aufeinanderfolgende Handlungen aus; es ist unklar, ob ich noch essen bin oder nicht.

Das Präteritum von *essen*, also *aß*, wird aber durchaus auch verwendet.

> Als du kamst, aß ich gerade.
>   Als du kamst, habe ich gerade gegessen.

In diesem Beispiel geschehen zwei Dingen gleichzeitig. Der Anruf und das Essen verlaufen parallel. In solchen Fällen greift man eher zum Präteritum (oder dort, wo ich herkomme, zur rheinischen Verlaufsform). Da es gängig ist, das Präteritum durch das Perfekt zu ersetzen, sind beide Sätze korrekt, dennoch klingt das Perfekt für mich im genannten Beispiel komisch.
War man jedoch mit dem Essen gerade fertig, so kommt natürlich das Plusquamperfekt wieder ins Rennen und kann nicht durch Präteritum ersetzt werden.

> Als du kamst, hatte ich gerade gegessen.

Oder man sagt:

> Als du kamst, war ich gerade fertig.

Alles in allem ist dein Satz vollkommen korrekt.